# Test whether there are 3 or 4 columns in data file

Tags: fortran

I have a small Fortran program that accepts a data file for input. This data file has two possible formats:

```
a 0 0
b 0 0
c a b
d a c
```

and

```
a 0 0 1
b 0 0 1
c a b 0
d a c 0
```

i.e. basic format is three columns of characters, space separated. We do not expect special characters besides perhaps hyphen and underscores.
The extended format has a fourth column with integers 0 or 1.

I am not certain of the best (and simplest) approach for doing this. I tried to test for a fourth column by:

```
integer :: a4, stat
character :: a1, a2, a3

open(unit=1001, file='Test.txt')
read(1001, '(a,a,a,i/)', iostat=stat) a1, a2, a3, a4
print *, stat, a1, a2, a3, a4
close(1001)
```

But this did not raise any errors when only given three columns.

Comment: Although not explicitly stated, the first three columns could also be integers...

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
read(1001, '(a,a,a,i1)', iostat=stat) a1, a2, a3, a4
```

is correct (I just don't know the reason for the '/' in the format).

But you have to test the `stat` variable. If it is zero, the read succeeded and you have four columns. If there was en error condition, the `stat` will be positive. You can then try to read just three columns and if that succeeds with `stat==0`, you have three columns.

I would actually read the line into a character string and read from there:

```
read(1001, '(a)', iostat=stat) line

if (stat/=0) treat_error_cannot_read_from_file

read(line, '(a,a,a,i1)', iostat=stat)) a1, a2, a3, a4

if (stat/=0) then
  read(line, '(a,a,a)', iostat=stat)) a1, a2, a3
  if (stat/=0) then 
    error...
  else
    n_columns = 3
  end if
else
  n_columns =  4
end if
```

Comment: Yes, I use it sometimes, to skip whole lines, but why here? Next read statement will move to the next record anyway.

Comment: The `/` may have been a mis-transcription of `1` - otherwise the `i` data edit descriptor is missing the required field width..

Comment: Ah, I had found elsewhere that ``/`` meant end of line. Perhaps I was mistaken?

Comment: Roughly speaking it means go to the next line.

Comment: Finally gone through the ropes on this one. It doesn't work if the first columns are integer -- which they also may be. But reading from a line gave me an idea...

Comment: If it is a single letter integer, it must work. Of course it will be read as a character, you must use the right descriptor! Or *.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @vladimir-f who proposed reading from a line.

The issue was getting Fortran to not continue reading from next line if a fourth column (data field) was missing.

In this solution, we read the first line in (only!) and use that as input for a formatted read, which fails if the last field is missing.

```
integer :: stat,fourthColumn
character(len=1000) :: dumC
character, dimension(1:3) :: pedline

read(102, '(a)', advance='NO', iostat=stat) dumC
if (stat > 0) then
    print *, 'Problems reading input file.'
    print *, stat, dumC
    stop 1
endif

! Test if the line contains three or four columns
fourthColumn = -99
read(dumC, *, iostat=stat) pedline, fourthColumn
if (stat .eq. -1 .and. fourthColumn .eq. -99) then
  n_columns = 3
else
  n_columns = 4
endif
```

Comment: If stat /= 0 you the value of the read variables is undefined.  Your test `fouthColumn .eq. -99` may easily fail. I did the cascade of the `if`s in my answer for a reason.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? But I could update the code where I removed the ``advance='NO'``, first if tests if ``stat /= 0`` and did a ``rewind``. But that wasn't the part you are talking about...

Comment: The value of `fouthColumn` may be undefined, you cannot test if its value is -99.